# Alphabet Layers In Python

Tags: python, loops, design-patterns, layer, alphabet

How to multiply layers without ankwardly repeating elif lines? Cannot get += 1 working. Or perhaps different string approach? I'm certainly new in Python.

```
layer = int(input("Give a number between 2 and 26: "))
table_size = layer + layer - 1
ts = table_size
center = (ts // 2)

for row in range(ts):
        for col in range(ts):
                if  row == col == (center):
                        print("A", end="")

                elif  (row > center  or col > center \
                or row < center or col < center) \
                and row < center + 2 and row > center - 2 \
                and col < center + 2 and col > center - 2 :
                        print("B", end="")

                elif  (row > center+1 or col > center+1 \
                or row < center-1 or col < center-1) \
                and row < center+3 and row > center-3 \
                and col < center+3 and col > center-3 :
                        print(chr(67), end="")

                else:
                        print(" ", end="")
        print()

CCCCC
CBBBC
CBABC
CBBBC
CCCCC
```

Comment: please share input and output samples. if possible describe your logic

Comment: Give a number between 2 and 26: 3. There is an alphabet square pattern at the end of code. Given number: how many layers of alphabet  starting from A to Z. I started to calculate  from center row == col == center and then adding distance.

Comment: Rough logic, you need to reverse your logic. for example, if the number is 3. create a matrix of 5x5 with all c letters(ASCII(67)). then traves from diagonal, say 2,2 in the second row, ASCII(67)-1(b). till the length of matrix  -n, ie diagonal(4,4). follow till you reach the middle of the matrix. in other words, you will all have a matrix of cs, then cand b. and at last matrix of c,b and a letters as your middle of the matrix

Answer (score 1):

```
user_input = int(input("Layers: "))
center = 25
layer = user_input - 1
counter = 0

import string
string_x = ""
alphabet = 26
list_of_letters = [True]
while alphabet != (-1):
    string_x = string_x + string.ascii_uppercase[alphabet-1]*alphabet
    string_y = string_x[::-1]
    string_y = string_y[1:len(string_y)]
    alphabet = alphabet - 1
    string_z = string_x + string_y  
    list_of_letters.append(string_z)
    string_x = string_x[0:26-alphabet]

dictionary = { }
variable = 0
for number in range(1,27):
    dictionary[number] = 24 - variable
    variable = variable + 1

differential = user_input - dictionary[user_input]
counter = user_input - differential + 2
helper_variable = counter

while counter != 26:
    print(list_of_letters[counter][center-layer:center+user_input])
    counter = counter + 1
while counter != helper_variable - 1:
    print(list_of_letters[counter][center-layer:center+user_input])
    counter = counter - 1
```

You can make this box of letters by creating a list with elements from 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ' to 'ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'. And then find a way to reference and print these strings exactly as many times as you want considering that 'A' will be 25th and you add layers with neighbouring letters. Do it in both directions using while-loop and helper variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can resort to `numpy` to prepare the indexation of the alphabet, and then use the prepared indexes to get your final string. This is how:

```py
# Get your number of layers
N = int(input("Give a number between 2 and 26: "))
assert 2<=N<=26, 'Wrong number'

# INDEX PREPARATION WITH NP
import numpy as np
len_vec = np.arange(N)                        
horiz_vec = np.concatenate([np.flip(len_vec[1:]), len_vec]) 
rep_mat = np.tile(horiz_vec, [ 2*N-1, 1])
idx_mat = np.maximum(rep_mat, rep_mat.T)

# STRING CREATION: join elements in row with '', and rows with newline '\n'
from string import ascii_uppercase     # 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
final_string = '\n'.join(''.join([ascii_uppercase[i] for i in row]) for row in idx_mat)

# PRINTING THE STRING
print(final_string)
```

An example with `N=3`:

```py
#> len_vec
array([0, 1, 2])
#> horiz_vec
array([2, 1, 0, 1, 2])
#> rep_mat
array([[2, 1, 0, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 0, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 0, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 0, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 0, 1, 2]])
#> idx_mat
array([[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 1, 1, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 0, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 1, 1, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
#> print(final_string)
CCCCC
CBBBC
CBABC
CBBBC
CCCCC
```

Comment: I jut can't get numpy working on my OS installed with. 2.7 & 3.6 python. It's  a mess. But I don't understand: horiz_vec = np.concatenate([len_vec, np.flip(len_vec[1:])]) Why horiz_vec is not starting 0,1,2 when concatenate first value is len_vec and second is flipped?

Comment: You're right! I corrected it but I forgot to update it in the answer. Now it is done. As for installing numpy, it should be as easy as `pip install numpy` (or `pip3` for python3 in linux).

Comment: I got numpy working with pip3,5 and python3,5. It was difficult to find what means that .T ? idx_mat = np.maximum(rep_mat, rep_mat.T) Reverse order of axis...

Comment: `.T` means transpose. You turn columns into rows and viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example with a regular python list:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

result = []

# Get your number of layers
N = int(input("Give a number between 2 and 26: "))
assert 2<=N<=26, 'Wrong number'

for i in range(N):
    # update existing rows
    for j, string in enumerate(result):
        result[j] = ascii_uppercase[i] + string + ascii_uppercase[i]

    # add top and bottom row
    result.append((2*i+1)*ascii_uppercase[i])
    if i != 0:
        result.insert(0, (2*i+1)*ascii_uppercase[i])
        
# print result
for line in result:
    print(line)
```

Comment: This works without extra modules. I have to digest it for a while.

Comment: Basically, it starts in the center, and adds the layers around it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    layer = int(input("Give a number between 2 and 26: "))
table_size = layer + layer - 1
ts = table_size
center = (ts // 2)
counter=0
print(center)
for row in range(ts):
        for col in range(ts):
                if row<=center and ts-counter>col:
                    outcome=65+center-min(row,col)
                elif row <=center and col>=ts-counter :
                    outcome=65+col-center   
                elif row>center and ts-counter>col:
                    outcome=65+center-min(row,col)  
                elif row >center and col<counter :   
                    outcome=65+row-center
                elif row >center and col>=counter :   
                    outcome=65+row-center+(col-counter)                   
                
                print(chr(outcome), end="")
        counter=counter+1        
               
        print()
```

Comment: This certainly brightens my mind! And it is what I was thinking. If it is possible cover the matrix with just few  if,elif lines. And it goes also full A to Z. I Still need to walk through the lines with a pencil and a notebook. Also that one print(chr(outcome)) line at the end is new for me. Not seen on many examples.